# how to extract points that have a relation with together?

Tags: matlab, build, build-process, relation

assume:

```
 A=[1 2
1 3
2 3
3 5
4 3
4 6
8 5
8 3
9 7
9 11
9 10
10 13
10 12]
```

the numbers in this matrix are index of a point cloud and this matrix show points that have a relation with together.
as seen points 1 to 8 exept 7 build a group and 9 to 12 with 7 build a new group. 
how can I find these groups?
I try using the second column and say that when I have not a number smaller than any unique number in first column so we have a new group.but in row 9 this condition is faild.

Comment: This isn't clear.  What do each of the two values in each row represent?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth any relation betwenn to points. for example points that are in a same surface respect to distance.

Comment: @Ahmad This represents an adjacency list for a graph, correct? You still need to clarify how you're choosing the groups and why your approach didn't work. Some code would be nice, too.

Comment: Are you trying to recover connected components of the graph?

Comment: @Shai Then why would row 7 `(8, 5)` be excluded from the first group when it's connected to row 8 `(8 3)`?

Comment: @beaker can't see the problem with `(8,5)`, both nodes belong to first connected component.

Comment: @Shai But both the OP's example and the output in your answer indicate that `(8,5)` belongs to the second component. Going through your answer to see if that clarifies it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the connected components of the undirected graph induced by your adjacency list.

```
G = sparse(A(:,1),A(:,2),1,max(A(:,2)),max(A(:,2)));
[num labels] = graphconncomp( G+G' ); % symmetric for undirected graph
```

Resulting `labels`

```
1     1     1     1     1     1     2     1     2     2     2     2     2
```

As you can see, 1-6 and 8 are labeled `'1'` while 9 to 12 and 7 are labeled `'2'`.

See [`graphconncomp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/graphconncomp.html) for more information.